# Statement incomplete in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-workbench

Im having trouble creating a function in mySql where it is throwing errors.

```
-- Function to calculate due date --
create function calc_due_date(checkout_date datetime)
returns datetime
begin
    declare due_date datetime;
    set due_date = checkout_date + interval 15 day;
    return due_date;
end;
```

[['return is not valid at this position'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXdWE.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a80Xh.png)

I am making a function to take `checkout_date` as an input and return `due_date` which is 15 days after the `checkout_date`

Comment: I tested this in the current version of MySQL Workbench, and it is fixed if I first write `DELIMITER` and change the delimiter. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html for details.

Comment: In what window do you enter your code?